# Gradle: Could not read settings file

Tags: android, gradle

I accidental ran

```
./gradlew heck
```

instead of "check"

now I get the build error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not read settings file '/home/.../ProjectFolder/heck' as it does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

What the heck? I just wanted to check!

Comment: edit your gradlew.bat file and remove that heck

Comment: I don't have any heck in any of the gradle scripts.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar problem, except I was running this:

```
  gradle -clean build.
```

And getting an error that it couldn't find the file "lean".
See our problem?
We both accidentally called the "--settings-file" option, which is abbreviated by "-c".

Get rid of the dash, and your world will be good again.
As mine is now.
:-)